# Delete instance from instance group in gce

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

How can I delete specific instance from instance group and resize group accordingly?

Following request just only detach the instance from the group but after that the group auto scaled with another new instance.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project/zones/zone/instanceGroupManagers/instanceGroupManager/abandonInstances
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Delete Instance provided you have sufficient rights:

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/example-project/zones/us-central1-f/instances/example-instance
```

Refer [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance)

Comment: Deleting instance from instance group recreate instance. I need specific instance deleted without recreation in a group.

Comment: You need to modify auto scale policy for that